USA Visa for Travel Agent
Can anyone let us know if travel agent get USA B2 visa? or usually they refuse the visa for travel agent.

Are you asking if someone who works as a travel agent can get a visa personally, or do you want to know about the success rate of visa applications submitted by a travel agent on behalf of someone else?

The rules don't treat people who claim to be travel agents differently from anyone else.

yes, for travel agent himself

The key thing will be what reason the person has to go to USA.

There are no specific rules or regulations relating to "travel agents". Their visa application will be evaluated on its own merits like everyone else's. It makes no difference whether the applicant is a travel agent or not.
